# Data Exchange Between two Raspberry Pi?

Tags: usb, connection

I want to exchange data from a Raspberry Pi A+ and a Raspberry Pi 2 B+. I want to transfer files on the Micro SD Card from the first raspberry pi to the other one.

What are the best solution for this ? A USB to USB Direct Cable Device ? Connect some GPIO Pin of the Raspberry Pi A+ on some GPIO Pin of the Raspberry Pi 2 B+ ?

How can I do this and with what material ?

Thanks, I'm a beginner !

Comment: You can do it with a normal ethernet cable, see: *[Local network between two Rpis](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/37554/5538).*

Comment: assuming you have an usb ethernet device on the A of course - more likely to have usb wifi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways this could be done:

- USB drive - copy the files from one Pi on to the drive, and then move them to the other.
- Network transfer - via a protocol such as FTP, SFTP. The Pi's have to be connected to the same network (e.g. via wireless USB adapters), you will also need their IP addresses and a server running on at least one of them
- [Serial](http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection) - there are two serial Pins on each Pi's GPIO, you should be able to connect them to get a basic serial connection:

  [image]
  <sup>[Source](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/serial-communication)</sup>

  You could then  emulate a network connection over that.

Comment: Or a pair of bluetooth dongles?

Comment: Forgot about that - I think they use serial as well

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion that has not yet been made is to use a PC with a card reader/writer (or if you are really well equipped, two of such things, which means you can do without the *stashing* mentioned below) to transfer the files between the Pis in an "off-line" way.  If your PC is a Linux machine it will probably auto-mount the card(s) as you insert them so it just becomes a question of finding an area to temporarily stash the files between reading and writing the two cards.

For those of you who still remember what a floppy disk is, this process will seem reminiscent of [disk swapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_swapping) and MSDOS `xcopy /v /s /m A:\*.* B:\`...!

Comment: Note - you probably don't need to use the MSDOS xcopy xD