# Can I connect a laptop and a raspberry pi using a cross over cable?

Tags: networking

I [found this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22835/how-to-network-two-ubuntu-computers-using-ethernet-without-a-router) for connecting two machines together using a crossover cable.  Would I be able to do this using a Raspberry PI running Raspberrian and a Windows or Ubuntu Laptop?

Sometimes I like to read stuff offline, and this would give me a method of doing so, while still being able to use a server-based wiki on the pi.

Comment: What Pi is that? I'd prefer a WLAN connection.

Comment: @ott The original, a model B+ I think; Whatever it is, there's no wifi on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but it is pointless, unless all you have is a cross-over cable.  I.e., it will work, but you can use any normal ethernet cable instead. The method in your link is outdated in so far as contemporary equipment (including all models of pi, and almost certainly your laptop) have ethernet jacks that can detect when connected this way and deal with crossing the lines appropriately.  There is actually a footnote on the accepted answer there mentioning this.

[This answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37596/5538) describes how to connect two pis together via ethernet and share the wifi connection on one with the other, which is a fairly similar use case.

Answer (score 2):

An easy option on a Linux system with NetworkManager

1. Edit Connections > Add > Create "Ethernet"
2. (tab) Ethernet > Device (dropdown) = **SELECT NIC**
3. (tab) IPv4 Settings > (dropdown) Method = "Link-Local Only"

Or to share internet from this host, change last setting to

3. (tab) IPv4 Settings > (dropdown) Method = "Shared to other computers"

Then simply connect from either laptop or pi with: `ssh USER@HOSTNAME.local`